# How to select the array item (array of objects) based upon a particular attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have the following array of objects
I am trying to filter the products by size in such a way such that all the products of the specific size selected by user only get rendered as you normally see it happening on an ecommerce website.

So for example if I select the size S, I only want the products to render which have the size "S" available in the inventory

part1 to grab the size picked up by the user

```
const sizeFilterHandler = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    setSizeFilter(event.target.value);
  };
```

part2 to grab the size picked up by the user

```
          onChange={sizeFilterHandler}
          className="form-select mb-3"
          aria-label=".form-select-lg example"
        >
          <option selected>Size</option>
          <option value="S">S</option>
          <option value="M">M</option>
          <option value="L">L</option>
          <option value="XL">XL</option>
          <option value="XXL">XXL</option>
          <option value="XXXL">XXXL</option>
        </select>
```

```
"inventoryInfo": [
            {
                "skuId": 47638228,
                "label": "S",
                "inventory": 227,
                "available": true
            },
            {
                "skuId": 47638227,
                "label": "M",
                "inventory": 330,
                "available": true
            },
            {
                "skuId": 47638224,
                "label": "L",
                "inventory": 325,
                "available": true
            },
            {
                "skuId": 47638225,
                "label": "XL",
                "inventory": 313,
                "available": true
            },
            {
                "skuId": 47638226,
                "label": "XXL",
                "inventory": 146,
                "available": true
            },
            {
                "skuId": 47638223,
                "label": "3XL",
                "inventory": 80,
                "available": true
            }
        ],
```

Comment: You are mostly there. Just filter the array of objects by ```sizeFilter``` using Array.filter()` in render.

Comment: @Harry yes but some items might have available as "false" so i only wanna render items which have the specific size and the available as "true"

Comment: Check my answer. The logic is there.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the array [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function.
Something like

```
inventoryToDisplay = inventoryInfo.filter(inventoryItem => inventoryItem.label === event.target.value && inventoryItem.available)
```

Comment: mate, the condition will always turn out to be true, some of the items will have available as "false" so there has to be a true or false check there aswell

Comment: Yes, you're right. I had missed the condition

Answer (score 0):

Filter and Map

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* XL is your value from setFilter */}
      {inventoryInfo
        .filter((item) => item.label === 'XL' && item.available === true)
        .map((element, index) => (
          <>
            <div key={index}>{element.skuId}</div>
            <div key={index}>{element.label}</div>
            <div key={index}>{element.inventory}</div>
            <div key={index}>{element.available}</div>
          </>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
```